# When do Batman and Bane first fight?

Tags: dc, batman

I'm working on a project on Bane and I am having trouble following the main storyline in the comics that involve Bane. In particular I am looking for the comic that contains Bane and Batman's first meeting and fight.

What I've gathered is Bane first appeared in *Vengeance of Bane* but decides he's not ready to fight Batman, then he appears in *Killer's Bane* where he still just observes and prepares for Batman, then he still has no interaction with Batman in #656 *Besieged*. Then I lose the trail and everything mentions their fight in the Batcave where Batman has his back broken. *Vengeance of Bane: Part 2* says they have previously fought, so I assume that came after their fight in the Batcave.

**In what comic did Batman first fight Bane?**

Comment: http://www.dcuguide.com/chronology.php?name=bane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bane and Batman's first fight takes place in [Batman #497](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_497) (Knightfall #2 - Broken Bat) published in July 1993.

This includes the famous "back breaking" scene depicted on the cover.

[image]

You can find a complete (chronological) listing of Bane's early appearances [here](http://www.dcuguide.com/chronology.php?name=bane)

Comment: This is perfect just what I needed and the link is just what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Note that in Batman #666 Batman (as Jean-Paul Valley) also fights Bane.

Comment: why didn't that dinosaur save Batman and eat Bane, what a jerk

Comment: @Stick It's animatronic.  You can't trust those animatronics.

Answer (score 4):

Bane and Batman first meet in the comics in *Vengeance of Bane*. This story explains the origin of Bane and how and why he goes to Gotham to break the Batman. Bane and Batman meet and talk (Bane threatens Batman), but there is no fight (just a batarang thrown) when Batman is investigating the assassination of some mob guys (Bane had killed them because they had betrayed one of Bane's henchmen in the past).

In the following issues Bane observes Batman. Then Bane puts his plan into action, freeing all the inmates in Arkham to get Batman exhausted by fighting them. Then Batman has to fight Bane's three henchmen. It is not until he returns to his Batcave that he meets Bane for the second time, and then they really **fight for the first time** (although, exhausted, Batman can't fight back much...).

Part two of Vengeance of Bane tells the story of how Bane

> gets back in physical shape and escapes Blackgate prison

**so there couldn't have been any fights between the two of them between the time Batman's back got broken and this specific time**. They actually don't fight in this second part of *Vengeance of Bane*, but Batman tells him that this time, with him not exhausted and Bane not doped with venom, he is ready for a fight. That might be the reference to a previous fight, the one in which Bane broke Batman.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, very specific!

Comment: @DasBeasto, actually it wasn't until recently, after seeing your question's edits, that I realized that you wanted the comic number. I thought that all you needed was to verify that there where no other fights before Batman gets broken or between that event and Vengeance of Bane part 2.